# How to more explicitly declare a variable than via const?

Tags: vue.js, webstorm, vuejs3, quasar-framework, goland

I have a component (`NoteComponent`) that emits `note-not-saved`. This message is handled via

```
<template>
(...)
    <NoteComponent @note-not-saved='() => noteNotSaved=true' />
(...)
</template>
```

`noteNotSaved` itself is defined in my `<script>` section:

```
<script setup lang='ts'>
(...)
  const noteNotSaved = ref(false)
(...)
</script>
```

The application works fine, I have however a weak warning from my IDE (JetBrains GoLand or WebStorm)

```
Variable noteNotSaved implicitly declared
```

**What does that exactly mean? How can `noteNotSaved` be more explicitly declared than that?**

Comment: Possibly the problem is that `script setup` is poorly supported by IDEs. But any way, `() => noteNotSaved=true` is bad. This is not how refs are modified, and it's unnecessary to write a callback in a template.

Comment: I've used script setup in WebStorm, and it doesn't have good support yet.

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero: I just tried with the 2021.3 EAP version but it is not fixed yet. I remember a discussion on the JetBrains forum about `<script setup` support and I thought it would be fine by now (at least there are now IntelliVue is updated for 2021.3 EAP so it is useable)

Comment: @EstusFlask: would you mind commenting a bit more about why this is a bad approach? And how it should be better handled?

Comment: Writing JS in the template when unnecessary makes it harder to maintain and results in performance overhead. Should be like the answer shows, there has to be setNoteAsNotSaved function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE may consider `noteNotSaved=true` as an implicit declaration of a global variable.

Try changing its value as follows:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const NoteComponent = {
  template: `<button @click="$emit('note-not-saved')">Click</button>`
};

const App = {
  components: { NoteComponent },
  setup() {
    const noteNotSaved = ref(false);
    const setNoteAsNotSaved = () => {
      noteNotSaved.value = true;
    }
    return { noteNotSaved, setNoteAsNotSaved };
  }
};

createApp(App).mount("#myApp");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="myApp">
  <div><note-component @note-not-saved="setNoteAsNotSaved" /></div>
  <div><p>Note Not Saved: {{noteNotSaved}}</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure what to change. I use `<script setup ...` so there is neither an explicit `setup()` nor a `return`. It looks like an IDE issue anyway so I will probably be better off rasing the issue with JetBrains.

Comment: Can you share a demo? Can't you do this: ``@note-not-saved="this.noteNotSaved = true"``

Comment: I will try to make a relevant codepen. `this` should not be used in Vue templates, the variable is automatically bound (adding `this` would generate an ESLint warning "unexpected usage of this")

Comment: @WoJ try the updated version instead.

Comment: `.value` won't work in `<template>`

Comment: It's in the function inside ``setup``

Comment: Ah, my bad, sorry. I was looking at another answer and mixed them up. Your solution will be working, I wanted to avoid creating two extra functions instead of just setting the flag. Thanks.

Comment: I understand, your example is valid vue code but the IDE is dealing with it as pure js...

Comment: *the IDE is dealing with it as pure js* JetBrains IDEs have actually quite good support for Vue, they are just lagging behind with some features (for instance they do not recognize `$q` as being used despite being declared - there is a bug report for that)

Comment: Good. I think your possible solution is the above if you don't want to use ``this`` inside the ``template``.